How to switch to a buffer from terminal with a unique partial name
I have a buffer with the name very-long-name-xyz-etc. This buffer is the only buffer whose name contains xyz.
From terminal I can switch to that buffer using the following
emacsclientw -cna runemacs --eval "(switch-to-buffer \"very-long-name-xyz-etc\")"

Is there a way to do better by just using the partial name xyz?

Write a function switch-to-buffer-matching that takes the substring and searches the buffer list for a matching name. Your function can then call switch-to-buffer with the full name.

Here's one implementation of the function @NickD specified:
(require 'dash) ; for `-find', `-compose' and `-partial'

(defun switch-to-buffer-matching (regular-expression)
  "Switch to the first buffer that matches REGULAR-EXPRESSION."
  (switch-to-buffer
    (-find
     (-compose
      (-partial #'string-match-p regular-expression)
      #'buffer-name)
     (buffer-list))))


I confirm it works. There is however a missing ) at the end of code.

Thanks for pointing that out. For future reference, the norm for such low-level corrections here is to just go in and make the change yourself -- the author will be notified automatically.
